# Loading an image

Tags: java, swing, graphics, overriding

This is the code I'm using to load an image called "boat.png"

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
       img = ImageIO.read(new File("boat.png"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("Can't load the image");
    }
}
```

These two lines generate errors

```
BufferedImage img = null;
img = ImageIO.read(new File("boat.png"));
```

Although I've included

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
```

Please help me find the error !!

Comment: You need to tell us the error. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Error is (cannot find symbol: BufferedImage & ImageIO)

Comment: You should not be overriding `paint`, Use `JPanel` and override `paintComponent` and dont forget to honor the paint chain by calling `paintComponent` super implementation as first call in overridden method

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  Well spotted, but another note.. `img = ImageIO.read(new File("boat.png"));`  Never try to load a resource, or perform any potentially long running action, within any `paint(Graphics)` or `paintComponent(Graphics)` method!  Instead it should be declared as an attribute of the class that is accessible within the paint method, and loaded at some time during construction.  Having said that, I will often specify an `Image` in the constructor of the relevant object, and let the user worry about the source.  They can get it from `File`/`URL` or draw it at run-time, for all I care. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ImageIO class is in the [javax.imageio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) package.

Try importing that package:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that `BufferedImage` is in the `java.awt.image` package, not just `java.awt`, so you need:

```
import java.awt.image.*;
```

or

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
```

Some IDEs will help you fix this error by suggesting which package to import - Eclipse certainly does.

EDIT: You *also* need to import `javax.imageio.*` or `javax.imageio.ImageIO` - but you definitely need one of the earlier imports too...

Comment: @InspiringProgramming: More errors which you still didn't think to provide the details of? That should at least fix `BufferedImage` not being known...

Answer (score 1):

```
  import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
```

this import statement should be included.